# Regex for emoticons in text

Tags: regex, emoji, emoticons

I have to find and replace all Facebook style emoticons in a given text, but can't find right regex to do so. As rule of thumb it *must match* all emoticons that user input intentionally and *not match* that one that can be part of addresses, numbers, shipping codes, links, random text ecc...

This one `(^|\s)(:D|:\/)(\s|\W|$)` is not working with all cases that I test (marked with `"must match"` and `"must not match"`):

```
:D "must match" Sample text for testing:
abcdefghijkl:Dm "must not match" nopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789 +-:D.,! "must not match" @#$%^&*();\/|<>"' "must match" :/.
12345 :/-98.7 "must not match" 3.141 ://.6180 "must not match" 9,000 +42
555.123.4567    :D+1-(80 "must not match" :D555-2468: "must not match"
foo@demo.net    "must match" bar.ba@test.co.uk :D
:/ "must match" http://"must not match"foo.co.uk/ "must match" :D?
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar
:D
:/
:D
:D
"must all 4 match"
```

live test case: http://regexr.com/3ad1j

I've also tried `(^|\s|\B)(:D|:\/)(\s|\B|\b|$)` and it is matching all `"must match"`, but also three `"must not match"`...

For sake of example this regex is only with two emoticons, in real case I have an array of 50 emoticons to find and replace with corresponding emojis.

UPDATE: new test case http://regexr.com/3ad6i with updated `(^|\s)(:D|:\/)(?=\s|[^0-9A-Za-z+-]|$)` regex, still some `"must not match"` to eliminate.

UPDATE 2: updated test case http://regexr.com/3ad6i with updated `(^|\s)(:D|:\/)(?=\s|[^"-(*+\-/->@-~]|$)` regex, works quite ok, can I improve this in some way?

Comment: be more specific on what your conditions are, why should " :/.
12345 :/-98.7 " match why shouldnt " nopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789 +-:D.,! " match what exactly are you looking for

Comment: it must match all emoticons that user input intentionally and not match that one that can be part of addresses, numbers, shipping codes, links, random text ecc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(^|\s)(:D|:\/)(?=\s|[^[:alnum:]+-]|$)
```

[**Online demo**](http://regexr.com/3ad93)

Comment: I didn't know about character classes, thank you. Online demo seems to not understand neither what is :alnum: and for now I tried to replace it with 0-9A-Za-z . Do you know if :alnum: work in Objective-C NSRegularExpression? Also is there a way to not include the first group in the result?

Comment: @Shebuka I slightly modified the regex. You're right, the online demo doesn't recognize the character class. I don't know whether this regex works in Objective-C.

Comment: @Shebuka Your new regex seems to work correctly. What do you want to improve?

Comment: This part: [^"-(*+\-/->@-~] is there more optimized way to say "not match all printable character except the ! ) , . ?" ?